# Spring + Hibernate few @Transactional classes are in one session?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a few classes annotated as @Transactional

For example I have first class which is Spring Resolver

```
<annotation-driven>            
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <beans:bean class="TestResolver" />
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </annotation-driven>
```

**class**

```
@Transactional
public class TestResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
                    ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                    WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

                    return testDao.load(Test.class, 1L)

            }    
         }
```

And I have controller class also annotated **@Transactional**

```
@Controller
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "go")
public class TestController {


    @RequestMapping...
     public Test get() {
         return testDao.load(Test.class, 1);        
     }
}
```

The problem is each time I access testDao.load(Test.class, 1) hibernate issue a query to database and do not pull Test.class id = 1 from a cache in a controller.

Why it does not use cache? this two calls happens per single request, but seems like in different session.

If I do in a controller

```
testDao.load(Test.class, 1);
testDao.load(Test.class, 1);
```

second time it uses cache but not when two different componetns execute they code..

Comment: I only put @Transactional annotations in my services.

Comment: Hibernate doesn't use a (second level) cache because you didn't configure one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I need to do

**Class OpenSessionInViewFilter**

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html

However never used it before, but it should allow to keep session entire request

Answer (score 0):

That `@Transactional` annotation on the whole classes is a bit unfortunate here (that's not to say it's a bad idea in general, just moe difficult to understand the problem this way), putting it on the methods would make it more obvious what's happening here - each of the methods called gets called in a separate transaction (unless one actually calls the second, but my understanding is that they're called sequentially).

Hibernate probably determines that it shouldn't use cache across two transactions.